# Three questions about the analysis of heapsort by weiss in his book DS & AA?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, heapsort

The author said that

-we will show that only an exponentially small fraction of these heaps (in particular (N/16)^N) have a cost smaller than M = N(logN - loglogN - 4).

Then he said that (also the ***question***)

-when this is shown, it follows that the average value of Md  is at least M minus a term that is o(1).

[and I wanna know how he got this conclusion.]

And he then said he will show that there are very few heaps that have small cost sequences.

Here comes the second ***question***. Dose (N/16)^N very small compared to the number of heaps of N items (the number is greater than (N/(4e))^N)?

At last, weiss said that

-the average case should also be 2NlogN - O(N) comparisons which is also the worst case bound (rather than the more linear second term in 2NlogN - O(NloglogN)).

The third ***question*** is that what the “more linear” means.

Thank you all!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try searching other sources for better explanation. As I understand, that book isn't really great for starting in DS. Check what others say about it

Comment: what is N? what is d? or what is Md? Provide more information about the problem (what is the cost? etc.).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about a specific programming problem, but rather about the analysis of an algorithm, and should be posted on http://cs.stackexchange.com.